# unable to create table using django syncdb

Tags: python, django, django-syncdb

I am quite new to django and web framework development and I tired my hands on creating tables by using the inbuilt django models and then running the syncdb command to create it automatically . However I am having trouble creating it
Here is my model

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    username=models.CharField(max_length=100,primary_key=True)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And the database configuration

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'djangousers',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': <my username>,                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': <my password>,                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '3306',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

And this is the error I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
execute_manager(settings)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 209, in execute
translation.activate('en-us')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 100, in activate
return _trans.activate(language)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 202, in activate
_active.value = translation(language)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 185, in translation
default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 162, in _fetch
app = import_module(appname)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/home/thor/scripts/django/quiz/dbs.py", line 4, in <module>
class User(models.Model):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 52, in __new__
kwargs = {"app_label": model_module.__name__.split('.')[-2]}
IndexError: list index out of range
```

any help would be greatly appreciated . Thanks in advance

Comment: is the model code in app_name/models.py?

Comment: I'm with patrick here.  Looks like your model isn't in the right module.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be defining your model here: `/home/thor/scripts/django/quiz/dbs.py`.

It should be in the root of your app module and named `models.py`.

See here for more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#using-models

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that Django have its own User model? don't waste time doing something that is already done! (that's the whole idea of Django)

More about it in: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/